# Applying SRP and OCP

Tags: java, eclipse, single-responsibility-principle, appointment, open-closed-principle

I have been trying to apply SRP and OCP to this code. The code should allow the Bank Employee to book or not book the hard coded appointments. I can't figure out what classes to create to apply these two principles to the code. I want to know what classes that I need and the inheritance I should be applying.

```
        package gradedGroupProject.nonPrincipledDesign.v1;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;

    public class ORIGINAL {

        public String name = "X";

        public List<BankClient> bankClientsWithAppointments;
        public List<Date> appointmentDates;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

            BankEmployee bankEmployee = new BankEmployee();

            bankEmployee.bankClientsWithAppointments = new ArrayList<BankClient>();
            bankEmployee.appointmentDates = new ArrayList<Date>();

            BankClient bankClient1 = new BankClient("u1", "p1");
            bankClient1.name = "A";
            bankEmployee.bankClientsWithAppointments.add(bankClient1);
            bankEmployee.appointmentDates.add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("20/12/2000"));

            BankClient bankClient2 = new BankClient("u2", "p2");
            bankClient2.name = "B";
            bankEmployee.bankClientsWithAppointments.add(bankClient2);
            bankEmployee.appointmentDates.add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("22/12/2000"));

            print(bankEmployee.bankClientsWithAppointments);



            for (int i = 0; i < bankEmployee.bankClientsWithAppointments.size(); ++i) {

                Date date = bankEmployee.appointmentDates.get(i);
                BankClient bankClient = bankEmployee.bankClientsWithAppointments.get(i);

                System.out.println("\nCandidate date = " + date + " with client = " + bankClient.name);

                System.out.println("1. Verify it");
                System.out.println("2. Do not book it");
                String choice = read("choice");

                if (choice.equals("1"))
                    bankClient.bookAppointment(date, bankEmployee.name); // we assume that we answer with this call to the
                                                                            // client.
                System.out.println("Appointment Booked");
            }
        }

        public static String read(String label) {

            System.out.println("\nProvide your " + label + ":");

            System.out.println(">");

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            String value = null;

            try {

                value = input.readLine();
            }

            catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            return value;
        }

        public static void print(List<BankClient> bankClients) {

            for (int i = 0; bankClients != null && i < bankClients.size(); ++i)
                bankClients.get(i).toPrint();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should take out the *generating* methods from your data entities, and move them to some other classes (to maintain **SR Principle**). The new classes would be your "iterators" (knows how to perform certain tasks).

For each iterator role, you generate an interface that specifies the "contract" for that role, then you could have many different implementations for that interface.
If there is the need to add a new somehow different implementation for that role,  a new implementation of the interface could be created, avoiding having to modify the current code (**OCP Principle**)